# Custom thumb in seekbar get flat

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I've got custom seekbar with custom thumb. I used selector for pressed state, the problem is that when I press thumb on slider it get flat and it not back to normal size after.

My code:

thumb.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb2" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb1" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb1"/>
</selector>
```

thumb1.xml:

```
    <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="18dp" android:color="#882EA5DE"/>
    <solid android:color="#2EA5DE" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

thumb2.xml:

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
    <size android:height="40dp" android:width="40dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="18dp" android:color="#882EA5DE"/>
    <solid android:color="#2EA5DE" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

tstyle.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tbackground"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/tprogress" />
    </item>
```

tprogress.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2EA5DE"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

seekbar:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/tstyle"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
        android:thumbOffset="0dp" />
```

I need that the thumb is only bigger when I press on it. But result is that:
[image: flatted]

And this is normal state (not pressed):
[image: normal state]

Comment: I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Still facing this issue. Did anyone find a solution to this ?